# Making Infragistics Winforms UltraMaskedEditor Behavior Less Weird

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I decided to replace my UltraTextEditors with UltraMaskedEditors to make things a little nicer for my users.  (In a WinForms App)  But the (default) behavior of the UltraMaskedEditor is quite different from what I've come to expect as standard textbox behavior.

1) The first field on the form (the one that gets focus on load) now shows up with a huge number of spaces auto-selected.  (The UltraMaskedEditor.Value = dbnull)  Of course I can start to type and it will delete the spaces, so it works, but it looks really wierd.  (looks are a big deal for users)  I want it to simply show up with the cursor on the left and no spaces added or selected.

2) If I click into any UltraMaskedEditor field it puts the cursor into the field at that possition--adding spaces to the left.  Again, the UltraMaskedEditor.value is empty before I clicked in.  When I click into an empty field I'd like the cursor to automatically go to the left most possition without inserting spaces.

3) When I assign values to UltraMaskedEditor fields it displays them on the screen with what appears to be random numbers of spaces inserted.

Is there a way to fix these characteristics so that the UltraMaksedEditor behaves like the TextEditor?

Comment: Also posted this question at http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/26779/98387.aspx#98387
We'll see who wins. :-)  (Infragistics has professionals answering questions--but my bet is ya'll will do a better/quicker job.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer the question:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/26779/98387.aspx#98387